# Debugging device driver installation failures

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, graphics-card

I'm trying to install drivers for my Mobile Intel HD Graphics card, in my HP Envy 16 2002ea.

Trying downloaded drivers from various sources (including [HP](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-envy-14-2000-beats-edition-notebook-pc-series/5091477/model/5119236/drivers) and [Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/53102/Intel-C200-Series-Chipsets)), but each time I'm met with:

[image: Mobile Intel HD Graphics]

This is a very disempowering dialog box, as the user is not offered any further information.

Where can I look for some debug detail on why the driver failed to install?

Comment: [remove the older drivers with DDU](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=807), now install the INtel first and in 2ns step the AMD drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Where can I look for some debug detail on why the driver failed to install?

Device driver installs will write a log file:

```
%SystemRoot%\inf\SetupAPI.dev.log
```

Which is normally:

```
C:\Windows\inf\SetupAPI.dev.log
```

Look in this file for any error messages.

> In Windows Vista and later versions of Windows, SetupAPI logs
>   information about device installation in a plain-text log file that
>   you can use to verify the installation of a device and to troubleshoot
>   device installation problems.
>
> If a signing problem exists, SetupAPI will log information about the
>   signing problem in the log file.
>
> The name of this log file is SetupAPI.dev.log, and it is located, by
>   default, in the Windows INF file directory (%SystemRoot%\inf).

Source [SetupAPI Device Installation Log Entries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/setupapi-device-installation-log-entries)